# Dependency injection with asp.net identity and property injection with dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I configure asp.net identity using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/)

```
  var container = new Container();
  container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

  //Identity
  container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppDbContext>();
  container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<User, int>>(() => new UserStore<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>(new AppDbContext()));
  container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IRoleStore<Role, int>>(() => new RoleStore<Role, int, UserRole>(new AppDbContext()));
  container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppRoleManager>();
  container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppUserManager>();
  container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppSignInManager>();

  container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() =>
  {
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && container.IsVerifying)
    {
      return new OwinContext().Authentication;
    }
    return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

  });
```

And configure a property injection for `BaseController` and my `DbContext`

My BaseController

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
  {
    public ISessionContext SessionContext { get; set; }
  }
```

My register in simple injector

```
  container.Register<ISessionContext,ClaimsSessionContext>();
  container.RegisterInitializer<BaseController>(ctrl =>
  {
    ctrl.SessionContext = container.GetInstance<ISessionContext>();
  });
```

My `DbContext`

```
  public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
  {
    public ISessionContext SessionContext { get; set; }
    public AppDbContext()
      : base("AppConnection")
    {
    }
    public static AppDbContext Create()
    {
      return new AppDbContext();
    }
```

And my simple injector register for property injection

```
   container.RegisterInitializer<AppDbContext>(db =>
      {
        db.SessionContext = container.GetInstance<ISessionContext>();
      });
```

I wonder if there would be no problem injecting  SessionContext property next to my DbContext, for every request it is also instantiated

Suggestions? This ok ?

Comment: Would `AppDbContext` fail (throw exception) if the `SessionContext` is not set?  Is ISessionContext like a current user session? +1 for `SimpleInjector` - my current favourite `DI Container`.

Answer (score 1):

There is any specific need to register those per single request ?

- IUserStore
- IRoleStore
- AppRoleManager
- AppRoleManager
- AppRoleManager

Weird implementations apart they should be fine as "per application" removing a lot of overhead

Also, you probably can add the sessioncontext to AppDbContext constructor and make a single registration